# I couldn't plot graph using matplotlib values from file

Tags: python

I want to plot ECG graph using matplotlib . y values from a file having float values and x value is incrementing(ie x ranges from 1 to 1000). went through tutorials and couldn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo Code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import pickle


#Y Axis : Generate 1000 random numbers
yAxisNumbers = np.random.uniform(1,100,1000)

#Save numbers to a file for demo purpose
with open('numpyData.txt', 'wb') as myFile:
    pickle.dump(yAxisNumbers,myFile)


#X Axis :Generate 1000 random numbers
xNumbers = [ x for x in range(1000)]

#Load file data to a list
with open('numpyData.txt', 'rb') as aFile:
    yNumbers = pickle.load(aFile)

#Plot and label Graph
plt.plot(xNumbers,yNumbers)
plt.ylabel("Random Float Numbers")
plt.xlabel("Number Count")
plt.title("ECG Graph")
plt.show()
```

Graph

[image]

Comment: How does this answer improve upon my answer as it relates to the relevant details (getting Y data from a file and plotting on a 1-based incremental x-axis?

Comment: I updated code to load data from a file [ guessed missed that part earlier]. My code contains all the requirements end to end, Right from loading  float values  from a file to plotting incrementally , to displaying graphs as needed by user. It gives sense of completeness and user can test by simply copying the code as opposed to making any changes/ modifications

Comment: Your code (after being updated) has all the requirements *plus* a bunch of extra stuff that is not necessary to answer the question. As the question was posted, my answer already had everything necessary...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal answer, based on the scant details provided.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()

Y = np.loadtxt(filename, other needed options)
plt.plot(np.arange(len(Y))+1,Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as p

aa=np.loadtxt('....your file  ....')
x,y= aa.T  # transpose data into 2 columns, assuming you have 2 columns
p.plot(x,y)
p.show()
```